# Get data from Json ever after exception

Tags: c#, json

I have to retrieve a set of data from Json. But often not all the parameters (there are almost 30 in total) are present. So, I would like to retrieve what ever data is there in the json and enter "Not available" for the rest. I don't want to use try catch for each of the items. Is something like below possible?

```
string title = TryGettingDataFromJson(JsonData, JsonData.GuestDetails.title);
string title = TryGettingDataFromJson(JsonData, JsonData.GuestDetails.title);
string guestName = TryGettingDataFromJson(JsonData, JsonData.guestName.title);
string address1 = TryGettingDataFromJson(JsonData, JsonData.address1.title);
string address2 = TryGettingDataFromJson(JsonData, JsonData.address2.title);
```

---

```
private string TryGettingDataFromJson(ModelClass JsonData, object obj)
{
    try
    {
        //we try to fetch the value eg JsonData.GuestDetails.title.ToString()
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Not Available";
    }          
}
```

Comment: what are you using MVC project where you are posting some data back to server ?

Comment: the easy way is to to create a class with all proprties  and then use that class as a model in your post method . asp.net mvc . web api are smart enought to cast back to your class  and set values where you have values.

Comment: Create a class with all 30 of your properties in C# and use NewtonSoft to deserialize the json in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just create a model class with all your properties and then use the method below to deserialize it in an object

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Proeprty1 {get; set; }
    public string Proeprty2 {get; set; }
    ....
    ....
}
```

Deserialize method:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string jsonObj)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonObj,
        new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
}
```

Call the above method like

```
MyModel obj = DeserializeObject<MyModel>(your_json);
```

Then you can use reflection or manually set "Not Available" to the properties that are null. I have wrote some quick code that will set "NotAvailable" to the string properties that are null.

```
public MyModel SetNotAvailable(MyModel obj)
{
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(var property in properties){
        if(property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
        {
            var value = property.GetVale(obj, null).ToString();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                property.SetValue(obj, "Not Available");
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Pass in the object you got after deserialization to this function and it will return you what you need.